# No permission to lock file when attempts to checkin after unshelve

Tags: perforce

Others has a change list that is shelved for me to checkin. So in my workspace, I first do unshelve:

```
p4 unshelve -s 111111
```

Then try checkin but fails:

```
p4ci -fixed QUEST -cr reviewer -- changedfile.cpp
```

And received the error:

```
changedfile.cpp - no permission to lock file
```

If I unshelve the changed file elsewhere and copy the file then overwrite the original one, checkin works. But his procedure does not seems to be legitimate. So what am I supposed to do after unshelve?

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like the Perforce `protect` rules have been defined such that you have `open` permission for `changedfile.cpp`, but you do not have `write` permission.

See: https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_protect.html

> open
>
> This gives the user permission to do everything she can do with read access, and gives her permission to p4 add, p4 edit, p4 delete, and p4 integrate files. However, the user is not allowed to lock files or submit files to the depot.

Versus:

> write
>
> The user can do all of the above, and can also write files with p4 submit and lock them with p4 lock.

Your next step should be to contact your Perforce administrator and figure out why you only have `open` permission, not `write` permission.

Perhaps your account was not placed in the proper group; protections in the typical Perforce installation are granted to entire groups, not to individual developers, and hence you must be in the proper group to have the desired protections.

Comment: But if I unshelve elsewhere and then copy and replace the file in my workspace. Then checkin is successful. However if unshelve chagelist locally in my workspace and try checkin directly it report this error. Basically I hope I can just unshelve and checkin, it that possible?

Comment: @seektrue For what it's worth this was the right answer for me. I actually did have write access though, but there was a "NoSubmit" flag left on my account, which I had to have cleared.

Comment: In some organizations, permissions are assigned to groups instead of individual users and the permissions of files (or folders) are set for the groups.<br>So you should check which groups the users belongs to and maybe one of those groups has the =write (meaning 'no write') on the problematic file.